# Failing to receive php response in form of html elements

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is what I want to achieve, send data to PHP using AJAX and jquery and receive a response in form of html elements and text.

```
    <div class="self">
        <div class="identity" style="display: none;">1234</div>
        <div class="name" style="display: none;">Mine</div>
        <div class="city" style="display: none;">Yours</div>
        Helo
    </div>

    <div class="self">
        <div class="identity" style="display: none;">444</div>
        <div class="name" style="display: none;">Oslo</div>
        <div class="city" style="display: none;">Kiki</div>
        Hi there
    </div>

    <div class="self">
        <div class="identity" style="display: none;">894</div>
        <div class="name" style="display: none;">That</div>
        <div class="city" style="display: none;">One</div>
        ok
    </div>


    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    
    <script>
 

 
    $( ".self" ).on("click", function( event ) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'get.php',
            data: {
                    name: $(this).find('.name').text(),
                    city: $(this).find('.name').text()
                  },
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success == true)
                alert(data);
        }
        });
});


</script>
```

I want to send the name and city to php and get a response back that I can put on a div element. my php code is below

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {


    $data = "<div>". $_POST['city'] ."is my home town my name is" . $_POST['name'] ."</div>" ;

    echo json_encode($data);

    }
```

Comment: `if (data.success == true)` cannot be true, you're not returning any `success` value of any kind from your PHP script.

Comment: How should I do this, and is the php side ok? able to recieve the AJAX query?

Comment: Don't JSON encode the response, since it's html anyway and you want to insert it directly into an HTML page. Just `echo $data`, remove the `dataType: "json"`in your javascript ,and then in the `success` function do something like `$("selectorForContainerDiv").html(data)`. (Although it doesn't matter, you probably want to just call it `response` or something, not `data`, since it's not HTML not JSON.)

Comment: Still not receiving any response.

Comment: @RobinZigmond removed the dataType: "json" removed json encode and changed the contents of the success function.

Comment: did you also remove the `if (data.success == true)` as @Jeto said?

Comment: Yes, I put back the dataType but passed an empty string, and got a response of all html, however the values I passed were not included in the response. I need the response to be a variable that contains html elements with values of variables passed. I should be able to receive `<div> Something <?=$name?> something </div>` which is contained in a variable `$data` but all am recieving is `<div> Something Something </div>` without the value of `$name`

Comment: This is what I want to recieve `ob_start(); include 'content.html.php'; $data=ob_get_clean();` the include file will be passed variables and the output will be html, I want to put the value of $data on the other page as a response.